# In play framework I am unable to connect to sql server where windows authentication is enabled

Tags: sql-server, playframework-2.0

I am trying to connect to SQL Server from play framework where my SQL Server is hosted on a different machine with Windows authentication enabled. I'm not sure how that can be done in play. I am new to the play work.

This is what I configured in my application.config:

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://hostname"
db.default.trusted_connection="yes"
db.default.user="hari"
db.default.password="MyPassword"
db.default.host = "hostname"
db.default.logStatements=true
```

Any help on is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing related to play frame work here , your need to have sqljdbc_auth dll file under your system32 folder and enable integrated security as true.

Answer (score 0):

keep sqljdbc_auth.dll in your windows/system32 folder and it will work.Download sqljdbc driver from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) Unzip it and you will find sqljdbc_auth.dll.Now keep the sqljdbc_auth.dll inside system32 folder and run your program

along with the above changes I modified my application.config as follows

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://hostname;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true"
db.default.trusted_connection="yes"
db.default.host = "hostname"
db.default.logStatements=true
```